# Where can I get server side api for OCR ( Optical character Recognition)?

Tags: image-processing, ocr, text-recognition, microsoft-ocr

Sorry if this question is silly or vague but I have been given the task to get ocr implemented at server side during my internship. Where can I get the suitable api to integrate it with my company's site. I have tried using the microsoft vision api but wonder how to get it to server! I am a newbie in IT field. So please help me out with your valauable suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See http://ocrsdk.com its probably the best OCR there is at the moment. Its not perfect and it's quite expensive.

Otherwise there is https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract but it is ancient, written in C++, sucks and leaks memory.

Answer (score 1):

There are many OCR SDKs that you can use in server side applications as well as cloud solutions.

**OCR SDKs:**

- Tesseract: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr
- Aspose: http://www.aspose.com/products/ocr
- Asprise: http://asprise.com/ocr/
- ABBYY FineReader: https://www.abbyy.com/pt-br/finereader_ocr/

**Cloud Solutions:**

- Google Cloud Vision OCR: https://cloud.google.com/vision/
- ABBYY Cloud OCR: http://ocrsdk.com/